# Is there a consistent pattern with 'sein' verbs in the perfect tense?

Tags: tense, sein-or-haben

I've heard the rule of how it is verbs of movement, but that doesn't really explain to me why bleiben takes sein in the perfect as well.

Comment: It's verbs of movement, verbs of a change of state and *sein*, *geschehen/passieren*, *werden*, and *bleiben*.

Comment: You might define 'bleiben' as a zero movement.

Comment: ohhh that makes much more sense. I also saw somewhere about transitivity. Should I ignore that? Also do you know where I can find a list of all sein verbs?

Comment: einschlafen is similar. And "fahren" can take both "sein" and "haben".

Comment: in which circumstances can fahren take haben then?

Comment: The transitive "jemanden fahren" takes "haben".

Answer (score 2):

You can see a "most used" list [here](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/deutsche-grammatik-inhaltsverzeichnis/grammatiklisten/liste-verben-die-das-perfekt-mit-sein-bilden/), it has a "complete list" at the bottom but I didn't check the long list. Note that some words may have both (like "sitzen").

Also note that when forms of "sein" are used it may seem like there is a "sein" verb but it actually is the verb "sein" itself, which can be confusing: e.G. "essen" -> "Ich habe gegessen." compare "Die Sache ist gegessen." -> On a second look one notes that "gegessen" here is not a verb in this sentence.

The rule is:

1. Verbs that describe movement (including non-movement like "bleiben", ...)
2. Verbs that describe state change (including non-change like "sein")
3. Some exceptions

To group the linked list by this rule:

**Moving**

- auswandern – ist ausgewandert
- bleiben – ist geblieben
- explodieren – ist explodiert
- fahren – ist gefahren
- fallen – ist gefallen
- fliegen – ist geflogen
- folgen – ist gefolgt
- gehen – ist gegangen
- kommen – ist gekommen
- klettern – ist geklettert
- landen – ist gelandet
- laufen – ist gelaufen
- reisen – ist gereist
- rennen – ist gerannt
- schwimmen – ist/hat geschwommen
- sitzen – ist/hat gesessen
- springen – ist gesprungen
- starten – ist gestartet
- stehen – ist/hat gestanden
- steigen – ist gestiegen
- wandern – ist gewandert
- treten – ist getreten
- zurückkehren – ist zurückgekehrt

**Statechange**

- sein – ist gewesen
- sterben – ist gestorben
- wachsen – ist gewachsen
- werden – ist geworden
- aufwachen – ist aufgewacht
- verbrennen – ist verbrannt

**Exceptions**

- begegnen – ist begegnet